# Checking if token is available

Tags: javascript

**Code that does not work:**
    console.clear();

```
try {
  test(token);
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err.toString());
}

if(typeof token === undefined) {
  console.log("token exists");
}

test(token);

if(token) {
  console.log("token exists");
}

function test(o) {
  if(o) {
      console.log("token exists");
  }
}
```

**JSBin:**
http://jsbin.com/qanuk/1/edit?html,js,console,output

**Question:**
How can I test a 'token' for existence where it doesn't throw a reference error if it doesn't?

All three of my examples throw a **ReferenceError: token is not defined**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
if(typeof token === 'undefined')
```

- `typeof` is a keyword, not a function
- `typeof` *always* returns a string

Comment: @r3wt: I'm a ninja ;)

Comment: you beat me by like 15 seconds lol. your answer popped up as i finished typing

Comment: Can you guess this was c# syntax bleeding through? Ha thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @MikeCheel: Never used C#, but I'll believe you :-P

Comment: Yea you call it like a function in C# and pass in the type as a parameter.

Comment: @MikeCheel: I did some tests and `typeof(token)` does work (in Chrome, not sure about other browsers), but the parenthesis are not needed and are rarely used.

Comment: I tried it too but it didn't seem to work for me. You put the right way which is what I am interested in anyways.